# How to prevent Google Search Calculator from converting all Units?

Tags: google-search, google-calculator

Does the Google Search Calculator Have any settings, URL arguments, or anything of that nature to control how it functions? I really like how it works in most areas, but it continually converts all of my units to metric.

> 2" * 6" = 0.0833333333 square feet (**OK**)
>   2" * 6" = 0.00774192 m^2 (**BAD**)

While I would prefer it if the calculator just left the units of the inputs alone, a secondary solution would be to just to convert everything to imperial, as that will at least make the results right most of the time.

For this secondary solution, is their perhaps a way of setting your Google account to metric? Or somehow converting a Canadian Account to American?

Answer (score 1):

You can force it with adding **`to square feet`** or **`=square feet`** or even shorter: **`=sq ft`** or **`=ft^2`**

[image: 0]